# How to determine if the user willingly disconnected from a Cast device?

Tags: java, android, callback, chromecast, google-cast

When an Android app gets disconnected from a Cast device, Cast Companion Linrary's callback `onApplicationDisconnected()` is called to inform the app of the disconnection.

But how can we distinguish between the case where user willingly disconnects using the media route button in the ActionBar and the one where connection loss is triggered automatically due to WiFi errors / timeouts, etc.?

Does MediaRouter dialog provide any callback informing of the disconnection action taken by the user or would we have to make our own dialog to catch that event?

Comment: I presume you are only referring to the sender side. What is the use case that you want to distinguish between the two?

Comment: The requirement is to determine if the user really wanted to end the session (and so clicked the disconnect button in the dialog) or if the disconnection happened to WiFi errors / timeouts / saved device data being lost.

Comment: You still didn't tell us the use case; lets say you were able to distinguish the two, what would you do differently in the app?

Comment: Would want to restore the live stream in the case of automatic disconnection.

Comment: If you are using CastCompanionLibrary, you may hook into the following two callbacks to get the type of information you are interested in: `onConnectivityRecovered()` and `onReconnectionStatusChanged(int status)`. CCL manages the reconnection for you if you have enabled that feature when you initialize it.